# Creating Proc Frequency tables in Python with count and percentage

Tags: python, loops, sas, frequency, proc

I'm relatively new to Python but made some solid progress however i've come unstuck with converting my process in SAS utilising Proc Freq one way frequency tables into python.

A scaled down version of my dataset is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Code':  [719, 719,719,719,719,719],
        'National': [1001, 1001,1001,1001,1001,1001],
        'Regional': [3005,3005,3005,3005,3005,3005],
         'Local': [2002,2002,2002,2002,2002,2002],
        'Collection Variable': [1,1,2,3,3,3]}


df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Code','National', 'Regional', 'Local','Collection Variable'])
```

Outputs in SAS would take this and add a frequency and percentage column for the collection variable columns, results as below:

```
National  Regional  Local  Code  Collection  Count  Percent
                                  Variable   

  1001      3005    2002   719       1         2      0.333333
  1001      3005    2002   719       2         1      0.166667
  1001      3005    2002   719       3         3      0.5
```

Is anything like this possible in python? I've managed to get the percentages, but running in separate columns but not able to get the additional columns.

Furthermore, this would happen for a number of different Collection Variables. In SAS it creates a new table for each variable, is that possible in python with some kind of loop?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 2 lines should be enough to get the `Count` and `Percentage` columns (it also accounts for `nan` values):

```
df = df = df.astype(str).groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'Count'})
df['Percentage'] = df[df['Collection Variable'] != 'nan']['Count'].apply(lambda x: x/sum(df[df['Collection Variable'] != 'nan']['Count']))
```

Output:

```
National  Regional  Local  Code  Collection  Count  Percent
                                  Variable   

  1001      3005    2002   719       1         2      0.333333
  1001      3005    2002   719       2         1      0.166667
  1001      3005    2002   719       3         3      0.5
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks, that works a treat. One question, if my df had x amount of other columns how would I go about isolating the columns in my original question so that i get your output or would I be better off creating a df with just the columns i need?

Comment: It would be better to create a df with only the necessary columns. It would reduce redundancy.

Comment: Thanks for this. How would i deal with NaN data in a column. For isnstance in my original q, if say the collection variable had a blank and the count was 3 I would want the percentage of 1 and 2 to show 0.6666 and 0.333. (So I show the count of missing data, but also the percentage of the non-missing data) Does that make sense? My percent column would read 0.6666, 0.3333 and blank.

Comment: Yes, I have made the necessary changes in the code. You can test it out. It works just like you need now!

Comment: I currently have the following (the 999 is to show me visually better which are missing values) but it need to somehow group this so that when the Code in dataframe moves to the next number then it does it just for the new code. This line works great when the dataframe just has one code. Can you help? df['Percentage'] = df[df['Gender'] != 999]['Count'].apply(lambda x: x/sum(df[df['Gender'] != 999]['Count']))